# In your opinion, what song structure does Glasvegas's "Geraldine" follow?

Tags: analysis, songwriting, musical-forms

I would argue that the song "Geraldine" by Glasvegas (embedded below) follows an AABA structure, as there is variation in the second A repeat; however, a melody from the original repeats before entering into a second instrumental.

However, I've seen it described [here](https://genius.com/Glasvegas-geraldine-lyrics) as following an AABCB structure. What is your opinion?

Comment: Prefacing a question 'in your opinion' on this site is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Tim To be fair, pretty much all musical analysis, if not all, are to a certain degree subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[0:00]-[0:44] Intro
[0:44]-[1:16] Verse I (The verse structure is AA')
[1:16]-[1:32] Interlude
[1:32]-[2:04] Verse II (The AACBC analysis considers the second half of Verse II to be the chorus)
[2:04]-[2:20] Interlude
[2:20]-[2:52] Chorus (The AACBC analysis considers this the bridge.)
[2:52]-[3:24] Guitar solo / Interlude
[3:24]-[3:40] Half-verse (A' of Verse II)
[3:40]-[4:03] Outro
```

The verses have a two-part structure, `AA'`, so the lyric form of the song is
`AA' AA" B A"`. IMO, the suggestion of an overall `AABA` form is better reflective of how the song is put together than `AABCB`. However, `AABCB` is not entirely wrong, just misleading. What they call `B` is better called `A'`.